# How can I describe someone in one word who forcefully describes or explains?

Tags: single-word-requests, word-usage, adjectives, terminology

I there a word that best describes someone who forcefully describes or explains them self to others?

Comment: Maybe ***overbearing***

Comment: This person is a narcissist.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe the verb you need to include is ***expound***. The noun ***expounder*** does exist, but it is unusual.

My own syntax would be something like: ***Jim expounds vehemently on why he thinks Britain should remain in the European Union***.

Oxford Dictionary Online

*expound* (v) present and explain (a theory or an idea) in detail: (trans) *he was expounding a powerful argument* (intrans) *he declined to expound on his decision*.

By itself *expound* does not entirely get across the idea of forcefulness, (though it is stronger than *explain*)) and hence the need to add the adverb *vehemently*.